# Jquery datepicker not working after submitting form in django app

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, datepicker

I have a Django app with some views that contain a jquery datepicker. The page shows invoices for a specific month (present month by default) and the user can change it any month he wants with the datepicker. That works.
The problem is if the user wants to see another month, when he clicks the datepicker for the second time, nothing happens.

```html
{% extends 'base_layout.html' %}
{% block content %}
    <div class="row">
        <div class="supplier_search">
            <form method="POST">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <label for="startDate">month: </label>
                <input name="startDate" id="startDate" autocomplete="off" />
                <input class="list_button" type="submit" value="show" />
                <button onclick="send_to_accountant()">send to accountant</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="select-month"></div>

    <div class="invoices_list">
        <table id="invoice_list_table">
            <tr>
                <th>invouce number</th>
                <th>company</th>
                <th>phone</th>
                <th>mail</th>
                <th>amt</th>
                <th>amt with vat</th>
            </tr>
        {% for inv in invoices %}
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <a href="{{inv.invoice_file.url}}" target="_blank">{{ inv.invoice_number }}</a>
                </td>
                <td>
                    {{ inv.supplier.company_name }}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {{ inv.supplier.company_phone_nr }}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {{ inv.supplier.company_email }}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {{ inv.total_without_vat }}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {{ inv.total_vat_included }}
                </td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </table>
    </div>
{% endblock %}

{% block jsscript %}
<script>
    function send_to_accountant(){
        var month = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-month :selected").val();
        var year = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-year :selected").val();
        month_year = month + ' ' + year
        var url = "{% url 'invoice:send_to_accountant' %}";
        var sel_month = {{ sel_month }};
        var sel_year = {{ sel_year }};

        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            data : {
                'month': sel_month,
                'year': sel_year
            },
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);
                //location.reload()
            }
        });
        console.log(url);
    };

    $(function() {
        $('#startDate').datepicker( {
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            showButtonPanel: true,
            dateFormat: 'MM yy',
            onClose: function(dateText, inst) { 
                var month = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-month :selected").val();
                var year = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-year :selected").val();
                $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(year, month, 1));
            }
        });
    });
    
</script>
{% endblock jsscript %}
```

I have tried several approaches after researching the matter without success, for example:

```js
$("#startDate").removeClass('hasDatepicker');  
  
$('#calendar_show_btn').click(function() {
  $('#startDate').datepicker('show');
});
```

nothing worked, any ideas?